# Why do battery makers advertise voltage?

Tags: voltage, batteries, amperage

I understand that voltage is an important factor for determining the amps of a battery. So why do battery makers advertise both the volts and amps of a battery? As a consumer, if I know the amps, why would I really care what the voltage is?

Comment: Most devices require batteries of a certain voltage.  Use the wrong one and the device won't work or be damaged. Similar to how you cannot use a 5v supply on something that expects 120v.

Comment: They dont list amps....they list amp-hours.  Its a measure of energy capacity.   A 5 amp hour battery can supply 5 amps for one hour, or 2.5 amp for 2 hours, or 10 amps for 30 minutes etc...  (Sorta...its not totally linear....)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two reasons:

- The battery voltage needs to be compatible with the gear that it's running. Too high a voltage, you'll fry the load; too low and it won't run.
- The total *energy* of the battery (watt-hours, or Wh) is estimated as amp-hours (Ah) * volts. So you can arrive at an estimated Wh rating by taking Ah * V.

Here's the thing. It's important to know what that battery mAh / Ah rating means. Generally, it is the mean current * time, starting from when the battery is fully charged (highest voltage) until it is fully discharged (lowest voltage.)

The challenge is that battery voltage decreases over time, and not necessarily linearly, either. It is also influenced by temperature and the nature of loading (steady vs. pulsed draw for example.) This changes the volts part of the volts * A * hours calculation. To get more accuracy requires an integral over that discharge interval (which is what a watthour meter does) to truly determine the actual total Wh capability of that battery, using a load that models your application. Some manufacturers will do that for you given a specific test condition, but usually you'll need to do that yourself if the capacity is critical.

So back to voltage again. There's this business with cordless tools advertising ever-higher voltage. What's the benefit? The tool using higher voltage pack can, in theory, give more motor torque than a lower voltage pack. It doesn't mean that the higher-voltage pack has more energy however; that depends on the battery cells themselves and their own mAh capability. Fortunately they usually list the mAh of the pack too, so you have at least some idea of the pack's capacity.

Then there's power banks. They seem to be fond of using the mAh rating of their battery, but not necessarily giving the actual mAh of the power bank output (which could be 5V, 12V or some other voltage.) This not only raises the issue above, but there's also voltage conversion efficiency to consider. Again, you'd need to characterize it if it's critical.

Comment: _"The tool using higher voltage pack can, in theory, give more motor torque than a lower voltage pack."_ - in theory no, it can't, assuming the batteries have equal power output. In practice a higher voltage pack usually uses more of the same size cells, so it has higher power output. The higher voltage also reduces current for the same power, which allows the use of thinner wires etc.

Comment: What you said doesn’t make sense. More batteries of ‘equal power output’ is… more power. If the battery stack isn’t the limiting factor for current (and it typically isn’t), adding more to the stack to increase the voltage will force more current through the motor. Therefore, more torque.

Comment: Manufacturers typically get more power by using more cells in series to make a higher voltage pack, rather than using larger cells for the same voltage and higher current. They do this so they can use the same cells for different size packs. But in theory the voltage doesn't matter - provided the battery can deliver the power it could be high voltage and low current or low voltage and high current - and torque is the same.

Comment: Consider this thought experiment. Connect a motor to a voltage source with no output impedance. Measure torque. Increase the voltage, measure again. What happens to the torque? Now, consider the internal resistance of a hand tool motor: ohms to tens of ohms. Compare to a rechargeable battery cell (LiFePO4, LiPo, NiMH, NiCd): milliohms to tens of milliohms. The takeaway: the battery isn't the limiting factor, the motor is. That's why battery packs for hand tools have steadily increased voltage over the years.

Comment: where are you getting toose motor resistance figures from, they seem extremely high.

Answer (score 3):

Voltage of a battery does not determine the "amps" of a battery. Voltage determines how much current will flow through a resistance. Voltage determines the amount of "push" the battery can give.

The current rating determines how much current the battery can deliver without damage. This will be measured in amperes.

The ampere-hour capacity determines how long the battery will last at a specified current.

If you multiply the voltage by the ampere-hour capacity you get the energy capacity of the battery in watt-hours (Wh).

You care what voltage the battery is because different devices are designed to work on specific voltages. If you supply it with too low a voltage it won't work properly (your light will be dim, your radio will be distorted, your computer device won't boot. If the voltage is too high you will burn out the light or destroy the electronics.